# Java Web app, controller and interceptor correctness

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I'm developing a new web app based on java 1.7 and tomcat 7, using spring 4.x and hibernate 4.x.
I would like to have a confirmation about controller's correctness, because in every request I need to check some conditions and 
I don't know if what I implemented is safe. 
This is my base controller:

```
public abstract class BaseController<BEAN extends BaseBean> implements Serializable
{
   ..........
   public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
       this.request = request;
   }
   public void setResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
       this.response = response;
   }
   protected final BEAN getBean(boolean createIfNull)
   {
       .............
   }
   .........
 }
```

And this is my interceptor, that makes conditions checks:

```
@Component
public class ControllerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response,
                            Object handler) throws Exception
   {
       super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
       BaseController<BaseBean> bc = getControllerInstance(handler);
       if(bc != null)
       {
           if(/*checks conditions*/)
           {
               bc.setValue1(true);
               bc.setValue2(false);
           }
           else
           {
               bc.setValue1(false);
               bc.setValue2(true);
           }
           bc.setRequest(request);
           bc.setResponse(response);
       }
       return true;
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   protected BaseController<BaseBean> getControllerInstance(Object  handler) throws SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
   {
       Field field;
       try 
       {
           field = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("bean");
       } 
       catch (NoSuchFieldException e) 
       {
           return null;
       }
       field.setAccessible(true);
       Object value = field.get(handler);

       return (BaseController<BaseBean>) value;
   }
}
```

I'm not sure that this "technique" is good, and my biggest fear is that if I have 2 or more simultaneous requests, Controller and Interceptor work properly.

I appreciate a lot your suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Phil

Comment: I would add one thing: my controllers are forced with scope("request")

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use `ControllerAdvice`. Have a class by the name `ControllerAdviceBase` along with your controllers and annotate it with `@ControllerAdvice` & `@EnableWebMvc`. Add a private void method inside the class, lets say by the name `initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest webRequest)` and annotate it with `@InitBinder`. Now, every request will first go through this initBinder before reaching your controllers' actions. And you can start off using this technique with: `String contextPath = ((ServletWebRequest)webRequest).getRequest().getRequestURI();`

Comment: I tried but the `@InitBinder` is fired only if I put on request a param. Then maybe `@ControllerAdvice` class should have `@Scope("request")`. Finally, how can I obtain controller's instance?

Comment: `@InitBinder` should be fired if you add `@RequestMapping` to your controller actions with `method` param set. If I'm correct, this is the normal procedure followed in any java REST apps

Comment: How can I obtain controller's instance from `WebRequest webRequest`?

Comment: Controller's instance? Why would you need that?

Comment: To initialize some private variables defined in `BaseController` that should be initialized before controller's start execution